# The FilterControlNodesFactory() method not working in devexpress 12.2 version

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I am upgrading devexpress 10.1 to 12.2 version and I am using this following code. However in 12.2 version the `FilterControlNodesFactory()` methods cannot take 0 arguments.
How to fix this issue?

```
public DevExpressFilterToSQL(CriteriaOperator Criteria)
{
    _criteria = Criteria;
    _head = (Node) CriteriaToTreeProcessor.GetTree(
        new FilterControlNodesFactory(), Criteria, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a temporary solution:

```
//...
_head = (Node) CriteriaToTreeProcessor.GetTree(
    new FilterControlNodesFactory(
        new WinFilterTreeNodeModel(new FilterControl())), Criteria, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the `FilterControlNodesFactory` class is not intended to be used anywhere outside the [FilterControl](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsFilterControltopic) internal code.
So the best solution is stop using this class and review the approaches described in the followihg thread:
[How to create object of type model for FilterControlNodesFactory() parameter](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q359692.aspx)